# MYSQL displaying value in single record from multiple row

Tags: php, mysql

first of all this is my first time posting a question here. If my question is already asked and answered, please provide me with the links to that question because even i don't know how to properly ask this.

so i have a table with records like this.

```
ID   ITEM_ID     DATE     OUT    IN
 1     1002    2019-01-20   1    NULL
 2     1002    2019-01-22  NULL   2
 3     1004    2019-01-23   4    NULL
 4     1007    2019-01-23   4    NULL
 5     1002    2019-01-24   1    NULL
 6     1004    2019-01-26  NULL   13
 7     1003    2019-02-03  NULL   35
```

how can i select it to look it like this in mysql?

```
  ITEM_ID   DATE_OUT    OUT   DATE_IN    IN
   1002    2019-01-24    1   2019-01-22  2
   1003         -        -   2019-02-03  35
   1004    2019-01-23    4   2019-01-26  13
   1007    2019-01-23    4       -       -
```

what i'm trying to do is more like concate from multiple row of same ITEM ID into 1 latest date of IN and latest date of OUT in 1 row

*edit : i've add more data set for more clarification of what i'm trying to achieve.*

thank you very much to anyone that have been helping me.

Comment: does the field DATE_IN exist in your database?

Comment: @rawplutonium no. only DATE field is exist. i was hoping if somehow to detect when IN if null then it would be DATE_OUT then if OUT if null then DATE_IN. if that even possible.

Comment: What does the final '2' in the data set represent? And see qhttps://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: in that case you would write a statement as follows : `SELECT ID, ITEM_ID, DATE as `DATE_OUT`, OUT, IN FROM tablename WHERE ID=1` Unless you create a new column i don't think it's possible to output current date in `DATE_IN`

Comment: @Strawberry if the '2' that you're referring to in 'IN' is the quantity of item. basically, this is a stock in and stock out table.

Comment: have you tried max() ?

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran i'm trying to figure out how to join it first before putting max().

Comment: What happens if there's stock in and stock out on the same day? Also, I doubt that a two-row data set can ever be fairly representative of a problem - hence my previous comment

Comment: @Strawberry then it would be the same as my example set of table that i have, with the same date. And there will be only 1 record transaction at a time. it's either IN or OUT. it's not possible to have IN and OUT at the same record. Also i'll add more data set for more clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
a.item_id, 
b.date AS date_out, 
b.out,
a.date AS date_in, 
a.in
FROM (SELECT item_id, date, in FROM your_table WHERE in IS NOT NULL) a
INNER JOIN (SELECT item_id, date, out FROM your_table WHERE out IS NOT NULL) b
ON b.item_id= a.item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If the table is called dta, then this would be:

```
SELECT dta_out.ID,dta_in.ITEM_ID,dta_out.`DATE` DATE_OUT, dta_out.`OUT`, dta_in.`DATE` DATE_IN, dta_in.`IN` FROM dta dta_in
    INNER JOIN dta dta_out
    ON dta_in.ITEM_ID=dta_out.ITEM_ID
    WHERE NOT dta_in.`IN` IS NULL AND NOT dta_out.`OUT` IS NULL
```

I used the following table create:

```
CREATE TABLE `dta` (
  `ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ITEM_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `OUT` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IN` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have your table created wrong, make it like this

```
CREATE TABLE `your_database_name`.`new_table_name` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`item_id` INT(10) NULL,
`date_in` DATETIME NULL,
`date_out` DATETIME NULL,
`out` INT(10) NULL,
`in` INT(10) NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

you should store the dates separately so you can select them more easy, and the query to show what you want is:

```
SELECT id, item_id, date_out, out, date_in, in from new_table_name;
```

To select the date you want from your table is going like this:

```
SELECT ID, ITEM_ID, (SELECT DATE FROM table_name WHERE OUT IS NOT NULL) AS  
DATE_OUT, OUT, (SELECT DATE FROM table_name WHERE IN IS NOT NULL) AS DATE_IN, IN 
from table_name
```

this select above is on your specific table with your specific 2 rows, please create the table as i posted at the begining of answer, that will make your life easier(i gave you the select aswell)

Comment: ups, honest mistake, check again please

Comment: I can't really see that there's anything wrong with the OP's design - or, if there is, I'm not convinced that this is it. Incidentally, the number in parentheses after INT, is almost meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can try with a left Join

```
SELECT a.id,a.item_id,b.date as date_out,`b.out` as 'out',a.date_in as date_in,`a.in` as 'in'
from table1 a left join  table1 b 
    on item_id=item_id and `a.in` is not null and `b.out` is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to fetch the desired result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
item_id, 
(SELECT max(`date`) FROM items WHERE `out` = 1 AND item_id = 1002) DATE_OUT,
MAX(`OUT`) `OUT`,
(SELECT max(`date`) FROM items WHERE `IN` = 2 AND item_id = 1002) DATE_IN,
MAX(`IN`) `IN`
FROM items
```

Here is the SQL fiddle

[SQL Query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe4041/18)